# Function in Oracle SQL , is there a different version of the TRIM function?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my sql :

```
V_FORMAT_VAL     := REPLACE( TRIM(IN_CATS_XY) , ' '  , '' );
```

But this is an different [format , than what is shown here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php) :

```
TRIM( [ LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH [ trim_character ] string1 )
```

I don't understand the code above. What is the point of doing a REPLACE if TRIM already takes care of spaces ?

Comment: Read the manual on what `replace()` does.

Answer (score 4):

TRIM only deals with spaces at the start and end of the string. In truth there is no point in doing the TRIM since [REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) will replace all spaces throughout the string, the most efficient way would be:

```
V_FORMAT_VAL := REPLACE(IN_CATS_XY, ' ');
```

As Replace will remove the string by default if no replacement string is offered.

Answer (score 1):

TRIM removes spaces from the beginning and end, then REPLACE removes any remaining spaces that were in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Trim takes care of spaces at the start and end of the string, or both. The replace is there to get rid of any spaces that appear inside of the string.

Basically, it would take a string like:

```
one two three
```

and turn it into

```
onetwothree
```

while also eliminating starting and end spacing.

Answer (score 1):

trim() eliminates the spaces at the beginning and at the end of a string. replace() removes all spaces.

Actually I think trim() is useless in this snippet.

just try this:

```
select '>'||trim('  a nice string    ')||'<' from dual ;
```

and this

```
select '>'||replace('  a nice string    ', ' ')||'<' from dual ;
```

and see the differences.